# Is saying that A gives B a present a spoiler? (Kaguya-sama)

Tags: discussion, spoilers, specific-question, title-wording

Here

[What is the kanji on the fan that Kaguya gives to Shirogane in season 2 episode 2?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/57625/what-is-the-kanji-on-the-fan-that-kaguya-gives-to-shirogane-in-season-2-episode)

I think this is a spoiler. I think it should be

> What is the kanji on the gift given in season 2 episode 2?

instead of

> What is the kanji on the fan that Kaguya gives to Shirogane in season 2 episode 2?

It spoils 3 things:

1. Recipient of gift
2. Gift giver
3. The gift

Edit: Wow I'm just finding out that ONLY UNTIL RECENTLY was the title changed to such. Initially the title was

> What is this kanji in Kaguya-sama's anime?

Well ok fine not the best title, but still I'm sure there should be a non-spoiler title that's still good.

Answer (score 6):

It makes little difference either way. When determining consider how "spoiled" someone would be I knew the information in advance. What is considered a spoiler is extremely subjective, the context it is made is important, otherwise everything can be considered a spoiler.

Comment: So this new title somehow doesn't convey the context enough? People know it's kaguya-sama from the tag and that some character gives another a present. What else is there that needs to be known?

Comment: Spoilers are subjective. We can't reasonablely cross every t and dot every i. Nor can we force everyone to follow a certain policy with an iron fist. Generally spoiler things are applied to thing that will give away the entire plot or major sections if known. But this can vary by media movies having the most immediate impact and novels having a bit less impact due to the size of their audience bases and how easy it is to consume that particular media

Comment: кяαzєя, I believe you didn't answer my question. I know you have this thing where you have to balance spoilers and context, and so my question is really about context. What's lacking in context with my title?

Comment: I don't believe spoilers are subjective. r/anime and many reddit subs have a policy simply to make sure your non-spoiler tagged stuff, ESP TITLES, are accessible to a 1st time viewer of the 1st few episodes. What you're doing here is saying that Kaguya is going to give a fan to Miyuki when really at the start of the episode Kaguya hasn't decided. Of course if the whole question post is already spoiler tagged talking about say s2 finale, then the answers don't need to be spoiler tagged as long as they don't contain info from s3 onwards. If I scroll anime stackexchange, then I will be spoiled.

Comment: We are not them and they are not us. What they do is their business. If everything is a spoiler to you then you'll need to look to yourself for introspective. It's unfortunate but we cannot capitulate to your request as not all of this revolves around what you want. The consensus of the greater part of the active community takes precedence.